# Laravel 5.2 `use` syntax

Tags: php, laravel-5

What is the difference in usage within classes of the `use` statement, in the examples below:

```
Use Sluggable;

Class Invoice extends Model
{
```

and

```
Class Invoice extends Model
{
   Use Sluggable;
```

Have not been able to find answer to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use statement outside the class is for creating a shorter name than the fully namespaced version of a class you plan to use, e.g.

```
use \Package\Super\Awesome\Long\Thingy;
```

at the top of a file will allow you to instantiate the class anywhere in the file by just

```
new Thingy();
```

You can also alias classes this way, e.g.

```
use \Package\Super\Awesome\Long\Thingy as OtherThingy;
```

and now you can instantiate this class with

```
new OtherThingy();
```

The second example you give is to include a trait in the class you are declaring.

Comment: Glad I could help! Don't forget to accept the answer if you found it useful.